# Scala, method call compiles with dot, doesn't compile without

Tags: scala

For the purposes of self-torture I have been trying to write my own implementation of `if-elseif-else` construct (`when-butWhen-otherwise` in my case). The funny thing is that the thing that I have written doesn't compile without a dot before `butWhen`, and does compile with it, and it compiles both with and without the dot before `otherwise`:

    `when(false) {
      println(">> True")
    }.butWhen(false) {
      println(">> hello")
    }.butWhen(false) { // Without the dot says "Boolean(false) does not take parameters"
      println(">> Goodbye")
    } otherwise {
      println(">> Something else")
    }`

To my untrained eye, the declarations of both `butWhen` and otherwise are the same, they return the same thing, so it seems they must behave the same. Also, when I chain the `otherwise` directly to the when clause, the compilation succeeds without the dot, too.

Could you help me get rid of the dot? Below is the code for the `when-butWhen-otherwise`:

`trait ButWhenTrait {
  def butWhen(b: Boolean)(op3: => Unit): ButWhenTrait
  def otherwise(op2: => Unit) // {}
}`

object when {
  def apply(b: Boolean)(op: => Unit): ButWhenTrait = {
    if (b) {
      op
      DeadEnd
    } else FalseWhen
  }
}

object FalseWhen extends ButWhenTrait {
  override def otherwise(op2: => Unit) { op2 }
  override def butWhen(b: Boolean)(op2: => Unit) = {
    if (b) {
      op2
      DeadEnd
    } else {
      FalseWhen
    }
  }
}

object DeadEnd extends ButWhenTrait {
  override def otherwise(op: => Unit) {}
  override def butWhen(b: Boolean)(op: => Unit) = { DeadEnd }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error caused by the next limitations: Suffix Notation for [**Method Invocation**](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html) is posible only for **Arity-0** & **Arity-1** methods.

Possible solutions:

**1) reduce method arity by splitting call to 2 objects:**

**-- UPDATED (error fixed) --**

```
trait ButWhenTrait {
  def butWhen(b: Boolean): ExecBlock
  def otherwise(op: => Unit): Unit
}

trait ExecBlock {
  // $ name of method for transfer execution function
  def $(op : => Unit): ButWhenTrait
}

object NextExecBlock extends ExecBlock {
  object next extends ButWhenTrait {
    def butWhen(b: Boolean): ExecBlock = if(b) EndExecBlock else NextExecBlock
    def otherwise(op: => Unit) { op }
  }
  def $(op : => Unit): ButWhenTrait = next
}

trait EmptyButWhenTrait {
  object next extends ButWhenTrait {
    def otherwise(op : => Unit) {}
    def butWhen(b : Boolean) = EmptyExecBlock
  }
}

object EndExecBlock extends ExecBlock with EmptyButWhenTrait {
  def $(op : => Unit): ButWhenTrait = { op; next }
}

object EmptyExecBlock extends ExecBlock with EmptyButWhenTrait {
  def $(op : => Unit): ButWhenTrait = next
}

object when {
  def apply(b: Boolean)(op: => Unit): ButWhenTrait =
    if(b) EndExecBlock $ op else NextExecBlock $ op
}
```

than usage:

```
when(false) {
  println(">> True")
} butWhen(false) $ {
  println(">> hello")
} butWhen(false) $ {
  println(">> Goodbye")
} otherwise {
  println(">> Something else")
}
```

**2) with implicit convesrions for boolean to object with apply method:**

```
trait ButWhenTrait {
  def butWhen(op :  ButWhenTrait): ButWhenTrait = op
  def otherwise(op: => Unit) { op }
}

class ExecBlock(b : Boolean) {
  private object next extends ButWhenTrait
  private object end extends ButWhenTrait {
    override def butWhen(op : ButWhenTrait) = end
    override def otherwise(op : => Unit) {}
  }

  def apply(op : => Unit): ButWhenTrait = if(b) { op; end } else next
}

object when {
  def apply(b: Boolean)(op: => Unit): ButWhenTrait = new ExecBlock(b)(op)
} 

// AND implicit conversion:
implicit def boolToExec(b : Boolean): ExecBlock = new ExecBlock(b)
```

than usage (as you expected):

```
when(false) {
  println(">> True")
} butWhen(false) {
  println(">> hello")
} butWhen(false) {
  println(">> Goodbye")
} otherwise {
  println(">> Something else")
}
```

Comment: The approach is sound, but the first version is buggy. When changing `when(false)` to `when(true)`, nothing is printed. There is also a more general problem that will affect pretty much any implementation (unless you use macros, or turn the control structure into a Monad-producing one, or add a mandatory method to call at the end to actually terminate the whole block): the simple expression `when(false) {  println(">> True")}` won't ever evaluate the body (println), it will just return an instance (of `ButWhenTrait`). +1 anyway as it showcases usefull approaches.

Comment: Another solution to fix the problem I mentioned would be to make the `butWhen`/`otherwise` chain an argument of `when`. But then the syntax is less natural.

Comment: Also +1. I started hacking during Hulu commercials, I'm so glad you chimed in. There should be a FAQ for this by now.

Comment: @Régis Jean-Gilles, Thank you for your comment. Error fixed.